# I can't choose in which heroku remote push my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I add a heroku app called 'myapp-production'. I could push in this remote via `git push heroku master`. Fine.

I created a second app on heroku called 'myapp-staging', and add this remote via `git remote add myapp-staging git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git`.

`git push heroku master` seems to correspond to myapp-production.

And when I try to `git push myapp-staging`, I have this error :

> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

How can I fix it and ideally be able to `git push myapp-staging master` and `git push myapp-production master`  ?

`git remote -v` gives :

```
myapp-staging   git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git (fetch)
myapp-staging   git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git (push)
heroku          https://git.heroku.com/myapp-production.git (fetch)
heroku          https://git.heroku.com/myapp-production.git (push)
origin          git@github.com:johndoe/myapp.git (fetch)
origin          git@github.com:johndoe/myapp.git (push)
```

Thank's in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your ssh public key typically `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is registered with heroku. You can check that at https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

Comment: Thanks a lot Juan ! I didn't have ssh public key yet. I add one and now it works.